# why cant i install Viber in 32 bit Lubuntu? I have following problem

Tags: software-installation, viber

```
$ sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i viber.deb
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
```

Answer (score 0):

> This problem comes from the package manager not shutting down properly. You could either restart your computer or open up the terminal and type in the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Then

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

*Taked from: [Reference](http://ariesyoussefian.com/2011/10/17/fix-dpkg-status-database-locked-process-ubuntu/)*